# iOS Google Maps: Coordinates Mismatch

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

One of our application's feature is to plot a location on the map, we will save it in our server and show it on the main screen of the application. We are using Google Maps and GMSMarker with draggable property set to YES. But there is a difference between the marked location and the coordinate obtained.

**Code:**

```
    NSDictionary *signDict             = self.imgLocationsArray[_currentIndex];
_toSaveLat                         = [signDict[TAG_SIGN_LAT] floatValue];
_toSaveLon                         = [signDict[TAG_SIGN_LONG] floatValue];

GMSCameraPosition *camera          = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:_toSaveLat longitude:_toSaveLon zoom:GOOGLE_MAPS_DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL];
self.dragDropMap                   = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) camera:camera];
[self.dragDropMap setMapType:kGMSTypeNormal];
[self.dragDropMap setDelegate:self];
self.dragDropMap.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.dragDropMap];

if (draggingMarker) {
draggingMarker.map                 = nil;
draggingMarker                     = nil;
}
draggingMarker                     = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
draggingMarker.icon                = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor plumColor]];//[UIImage imageNamed:@"MoveablePin"];
draggingMarker.position            = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_toSaveLat, _toSaveLon);
draggingMarker.tappable            = NO;
draggingMarker.draggable           = YES;
draggingMarker.map                 = self.dragDropMap;

-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
NSLog(@"marker dragged to location: %f,%f", marker.position.latitude, marker.position.longitude);
_toSaveLat                         = marker.position.latitude;
_toSaveLon                         = marker.position.longitude;
}
```

**[image: Sample result]**

Am I missing something in the code or anything else? Please suggest a solution or workaround to get this fixed. Thanks!

**Testing Environment**

- xCode - 7.0
- Google Maps SDK version - 1.10.3 (Using pod)
- Device - iPhone 5S, iPhone 6plus
- iOS - 9.0.2

Comment: Not sure about your problem, but your code indentation looks like a stack trace ! :')

Comment: I use a formatter in xcode.  Guess, it is hard to read it! :|

Comment: Which provider are you using? and have you checked the accuracy of the returned location?

Comment: Yes. The accuracy seems to be correct.
I found when I use smaller images as marker it gives exact location with 100% accuracy..